# como hacer un bucle y con que: for o while?

Tags: python

Estoy apenas aprendiendo Python y cree un pequeño programita (o algo parecido a un programa) que busca equipos en una pequeña lista, el usuario introduce el nombre, si el equipo ya esta, le avisa y si no esta, le avisa igualmente pero le pregunta si quiere agrgarlo o no.

Hasta ahi llega el programa. Yo lo que quiero hacer ahora es que cuando el usuario diga, por ejemplo: No, a la pregunta de si quiere agregar el equipo, el programa le pregunte si desea continuar o salir. Listo, esto lo se hacer, pero lo que no tengo claro es como hago para que si el usuario decide continuar, como hacer que el codigo vuelva a la parte para introducir el nombre de equipo y empezar la consulta nuevamente.

Lo intente con WHILE pero me decia que algunas variables no estaban definidas, segun pude entender, tendria que establecer la variable antes del while y luego modificarla dentro del bucle.

La otra opcion seria con FOR, pero esta opcion al parecer no deja modificar la variable de control como si lo hace while.

Entonces estoy estancado ahi.

Voy a poner el codigo a ver que me sugieren y como hacerlo:

```
teams = ["Warriors", "Jazz", "Lakers", "Heat", "Nets"]

from ast import Continue
import msvcrt

intro = input("Introduce nombre del equipo ")

if not intro in teams:
    print("El equipo no se encuentra ")
    opcion = input("Desea agregar el equipo? ")
    if opcion == ("Si"):
        teams.append(intro)
        print("Se agrego el equipo ",intro,"a la lista")
        print(teams)
    
if opcion == "No":
    print("No quiso agregar el equipo a la lista")

else:
    print("El equipo ya se encuentra en la lista")
    print(teams)


print("Presione cualquier tecla para salir")

msvcrt.getch()
```

Se que quizas es una tonteria y supongo que tendran sugerencias de como simplificar mas el codigo y seran bienvenidas, de hecho, las espero atentamente. Solo llevo un par de dias aprendiendo Python.

Gracias.

Comment: Las líneas de la 16 a la 20 están mal identadas eso hace que `opción` en el segundo if esté fuera del ámbito del bloque donde se definió la variable,  así que si el usuario teclea `No`, salta la excepción `NameError` en la sentencia `if opcion == "No":`  de la línea 16, corrigiendo la identación el programa hace lo que describes.

Comment: Cuando me pregunta si quiero aggregar el equipo y le digo que No, me muestra en pantalla lo que se le señala que muestre y me funciona tanto sin la identacion como con la identacion, creo que no hace diferencia... Si puedes explicarme por que hace lo mismo en ambos casos, te lo agradeceria. 

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Para la lógica del programa, con `while`, para continuar o salir, se puede asignar una variable con el valor de `False` y cambiar ese valor a `True` después de preguntar si quiere salir o no.

```
equipos = ["Warriors", "Jazz", "Lakers", "Heat", "Nets"]

continuar = True

while continuar:
    revisar_equipo = input("Introduce nombre del equipo ")
    if revisar_equipo in equipos:
        print("El equipo ya está en la lista")
        print("Los equipos son: ", equipos)
    else:
        agregar_equipo = str.lower(
            input("El equipo no está en la lista, ¿desea agregarlo? (s/n) ")
        )
        match agregar_equipo:
            case "s":
                equipos.append(revisar_equipo)
                print("Los equipos son: ", equipos)
            case "n":
                print("Los equipos son: ", equipos)
            case _:
                print("Opción no válida")
    continuar = str.lower(input("¿Desea continuar? (s/n) "))
    if continuar == "n":
        continuar = False
```

Salida de ejemplo

```
Introduce nombre del equipo Bulls
El equipo no está en la lista, ¿desea agregarlo? (s/n) s
Los equipos son:  ['Warriors', 'Jazz', 'Lakers', 'Heat', 'Nets', 'Bulls']
¿Desea continuar? (s/n) s
Introduce nombre del equipo Nets
El equipo ya está en la lista
Los equipos son:  ['Warriors', 'Jazz', 'Lakers', 'Heat', 'Nets', 'Bulls']
¿Desea continuar? (s/n) n
```

En este caso estamos utilizando un bloque `while False` para dar seguimiento a la variable `continuar` cuando cambia su valor a `False` se sale del bucle `while`

Hay un ejemplo muy sencillo de esta lógica en esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/a/45511209/1436666 de la versión de Stack Overflow en inglés.

Y en el caso de decidir si agregamos o no el equipo, usé un bloque `match / case` en las líneas de la 14 a la 21 https://docs.python.org/es/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=match#match-statements

Comment: Gracias bro... Funciono a la perfeccion y la logica se entendio inmediatamente... Veo que andaba yo perdido.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tengase en cuenta que el match-case fue agregado apenas en Python 3.10. por lo que aun es nuevo y este código daría error en versiones anteriores.